# Is a cookie secure in a HTTPS connection?

Tags: php, cookies

Is a cookie secure in a HTTPS connection?

Comment: No, not automatically. Using https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie or the analogous native functions, with `$cookie->setSecureOnly(true);` it will be *safe against hijacking* over un-secure HTTP, with `$cookie->setHttpOnly(true);` it will be *safe against hijacking* via XSS vulnerabilities in your page, and so on. So in order to judge whether a cookie is "safe", you need to define the threat model first. Cookie theft over plain HTTP or XSS is what you should usually care about.

Comment: @caw does it with in http for testing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is transmitted to and from the server encrypted, so it's as secure as TLS is.

You can also flag a cookie as being intended only for client->server communication, and block access from client-side Javascript, by adding the "HttpOnly" flag in the "Set-cookie" response header.

*edit* — and as @Bruno suggests, you can also use the "secure" flag (in the same header) to tell the browser that the cookie should only be sent back to the server in https requests. As @D.W. points out in a newer comment, that can be quite important, as you almost certainly don't want your important secured cookies probably to be transmitted on unsecured interactions (say, prior to login from a non-secure public portion of a site). If *all* the interactions with a particular cookie domain are HTTPS, then that might not be necessary, but it's such a simple thing that there's no reason not to do it.

*edit* — update, a long time later: use the `secure` flag :)

Comment: It's also worth using the secure cookie flag.

Comment: This answer is erroneous.  The cookie is only "as secure as TLS" if the secure flag is set.  Otherwise, a man-in-the-middle or potentially a passive eavesdropper can learn the cookie value (because it will be sent in the clear over unencrypted sessions if the secure flag is not set).

Comment: @D.W. That's a good point - I'll add that to the answer.  Note that I had already mentioned the "secure" flag and its role.

Comment: Pointy, thanks for the update! That's a partial improvement. However, the first sentence is still incorrect.  If you don't set the secure cookie, then it is not correct that the cookie is as secure as TLS.  A network attacker (e.g., a MITM) can cause your browser to visit a non-https site without your knowledge and thus disclose the cookie, without breaking TLS.  Your last paragraph fails to recognize that an attacker can force you to visit a non-https site without your knowledge, so it is impossible to ensure that all interactions will be over HTTPS; therefore, you must set the secure flag.

Comment: @D.W well I guess it's a semantic issue - by "secure as TLS", what I mean is that the cookie, **when transmitted via SSL/TLS**, is secure. That is, the sentence explicitly is about when the cookie "is transmitted to and from the server encrypted."  When it's **not** encrypted, of course, it's not secure :-)

Comment: @Pointy: no, it's not a semantic issue, you didn't get D.W.'s point!

Comment: @markus-tharkun I think I do understand his point, and I know what the "secure" flag does. When it's properly used, then the cookie will be secure, and its proper use is required to make sure that the cookie isn't ever transmitted in the clear.

Comment: The point is that even if ALL interactions are https and the flag is off, there is a vector.

Comment: @markus-tharkun ah OK - I did indeed misunderstand the MITM scheme

Answer (score 7):

Cookies are sent within the HTTP header. Thus they are as secure as the HTTPS connection which depends on a lot of SSL/TLS parameters like cipher strength or length of the public key.

Please keep in mind that unless you set the `Secure` flag for your Cookie, the Cookie can be transmitted over an unsecure HTTP connection. There are man-in-the-middle attacks that use such unsecure Cookies to steal session information. So, unless you have a good reason not to, always set the Secure flag for Cookies when you want them only transmitted over HTTPS.

Comment: Is there a way to test with local host using this method

Answer (score 6):

In the connection, yes. But It's still stored on the client's machine unencrypted.

Comment: How can attackers get a hold of that?